# Why we need .show when use .fade

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Learning boostrap and especially alerts somehow looks strange to me to use `.show` class and how this class prevents the transition until the button close

I tried to find the background of behavior above with no success

```html
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Your HTML is not valid. Divs are not self-closing

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: none of those backslashes should be there. Remove them.

Comment: Sorry for wrong code. I don't know what happend with editor and made my code a mess. Then I tried to fix it but I didn't see the slashes. So I fixed the code. Now its fine( if you add bootstrap 5).